# Pythondialog: Unable to retrieve the version of the dialog-like backend

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, dialog

Minimal code example, run on OSX and Python 3:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from dialog import Dialog

d = Dialog(dialog="dialog")
sel = d.menu("Test",
    choices=[ ("FooTag", "Foo", False, "FooHelp"),
     ("BarTag", "Bar", True, "BarHelp")]
    )
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
  d = Dialog(dialog="dialog")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dialog.py", line 1371, in __init__
  self.backend_version())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/dialog.py", line 2012, in backend_version
  "{1!r}".format(self._dialog_prg, output))
dialog.UnableToRetrieveBackendVersion: Unable to retrieve the version of the dialog-like backend: unable to parse the output of '/usr/local/bin/dialog --print-version': ''
```

However, `dialog` reports correctly:

```
 > dialog --print-version
 Version: 1.1-20100428
 >
```

Nothing changes, if I use the absolut path `/usr/local/bin/dialog`. I guess, it is an install problem, but I've no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found yourself, the problem is caused by the fact that your dialog program prints its version on stdout whereas more recent versions print it on stderr. So, the string pythondialog tries to parse as a version number is empty in such a case.

pythondialog 3.2.2rc1 (latest release at the time of this writing) detects this situation and automatically reruns `dialog --stdout --print-version`, making sure this time to read from dialog's stdout stream. Since this is only done once at `Dialog` instance creation (the backend version being cached), the impact of this workaround is minimal.

It is better than your solution (passing `use_stdout=True` to the `Dialog` constructor), because it allows the rest of pythondialog to use dialog's stderr stream normally: the use of --stdout is only limited to retrieving the version of dialog. On the contrary, the solution you found will pass `--stdout` to all dialog calls which, according to the dialog(1) manual page, may fail "depending on the platform and your environment".

Had you reported this problem on the pythondialog [issue tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pythondialog/_list/tickets) or [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/pythondialog/mailman/), the workaround I mentioned here would certainly have been implemented earlier...

Answer (score 0):

Your example with little fixes for on my computer (i changed `False` to `'False'`). Your issue is that version is not matched against regex. This is code from pythondialog:

```
mo = self._print_version_cre.match(output)                                                                                    
if mo:                                                                      
    return mo.group("version")                                              
else:                                                                       
    raise UnableToRetrieveBackendVersion(                                   
        "unable to parse the output of '{0} --print-version': "             
        "{1!r}".format(self._dialog_prg, output))                      

#this is located upper
_print_version_cre = re.compile(r"^Version:[ \t]+(?P<version>.+?)[ \t]*$", re.MULTILINE)
```

I've tested your version with this regexp and it matched on my computer, but I guess you have other version of pythondialog. So check `_print_version_cre` in your `dialog.py` and try to much with dialog version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, but I have found that the problem is not the parsing but the stream used: `dialog` on (at least my) OSX uses stdout but stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:
`dialog` in OSX reports to stdout, not stderr.
By using

```
d = Dialog(dialog="dialog", use_stdout=True)
```

I get the expected result.